# IOS- App crashes when click on push notification only happen when app stat is killed

Tags: ios

I build the IOS app and i have used push notifications on it. When my app state is background or foreground the push notification click work fine but when state is killed then i click on the notification app crashes, and i am unable to see log because app already in killed state. what is the reason for it?

I am using following code in AppDelegate:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    notificaionsCount = "\(UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber)"

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    brainClient = BTAPIClient.init(authorization: ProjectSingletenClass.shared.clientTokenOrTokenizationKey)
    BTUIKAppearance.darkTheme()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = ProjectSingletenClass.shared.publishableKeyForStripe
    sinchManagedPush = Sinch.managedPush(with: SINAPSEnvironment.development)
    sinchManagedPush?.delegate = self
    sinchManagedPush?.setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically()
    sinchManagedPush?.registerUserNotificationSettings()
    let dispatch_Queue : DispatchQueue? = DispatchQueue.init(label: "Latter")
    pushRegistry = PKPushRegistry.init(queue: dispatch_Queue)
    pushRegistry.delegate = self
    //let pushTypeSet : Set<PKPushType>?
    pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = NSSet.init(object: PKPushType.voIP) as? Set<PKPushType>
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(tokenRefreshNotification(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)
    registerForPushNotifications(application)
    SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.cherryRed)

    return true
}
```

Comment: Can you show your notification click handler. ?

Comment: Dear sir its not crash for handler because , i checked it . I have commented complete block of handler still it has crashed.

Comment: Your entire implementation of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is wrong. You are doing way too much here. Your app is trying to launch. You need to return true immediately.